# Getting PageRank

Tags: java, c++, search-engine, google-search, pagerank

How can I retrieve pagerank of any page indexed by google? Has Google any API or page for this?

Comment: I forgot to add that I want to make it programmable.

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions only. Websites are considered off topic. Please read the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq). Programming questions (if this was one) would be asked on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: please don't post this question again at Stack Overflow; it will be migrated there and your SO account will take over ownership automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the PageRank by using an HTTP request:

```
http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&hl=en&ch=61470319184&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&features=Rank&q=info:http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php%3Ft%3D164713
```

Just figure out what "ch" is used for and you should be good to go.

You could also try [this site](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/PageRank).

Comment: what's ch ?? Is it your api number or what ??

Answer (score 1):

Check this article from [MkYong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-google-pagerank-pr-in-java/) on how to get PageRank in plain Java.

It gives an implementation of the Bob Jenkins hashing algorithm used to calculate the `ch` value.